# v4l2-ctl not changing from default webcam

Tags: v4l2

I am using v4l2-ctl from command line to change exposure values of usb camera but I cannot change the device from built in webcam 
When I am using `v4l2-ctl d /dev/video1` - it gives no error but it does nothing at all

Comment: Why `v4l2-ctl d /dev/video1`? Shouldn't it be `v4l2-ctl -c /dev/video1` ?

Comment: I don't think that this is a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

You might be using the wrong cmd.

- First of all, you need to specify `-d` to select a different device (mind the `-`-prefix; it is missing in the Q).

  but simply running `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1` will not do anything with the device (you don't specify *what* to do)
- So you also need to tell `v4l2-ctl` to change the exposure-time (or whatever you want to do) with the `-c <ctrl>=<val>` switch

So your command should look like:

```
 v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 -c exposure_absolute=3000
```

but then, your device simply may not support setting the exposure time and simply ignore any requests (it *should not* announce support for setting the exposure if it cannot change it, but often device drivers are a bit easygoing)